# Почему не срабатывает RewriteRule в .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

Прописаны RewriteRule для контроллеров таким образом:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)/([0-9]+).html$ /?controller=$1&action=$2&id=$3&%{QUERY_STRING} [NS,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([a-z]+).html$ /?controller=$1&action=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [NS,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+).html$ /?controller=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [NS,L]
```

Но если набрать site.ru/?controller=about , то он будет переходить и по этому адресу тоже. Хотя по идее должен же редиректить на site.ru/about.html
Как исправить?

Comment: не должен. а query_string добавляется флагом QSA а не руками

Comment: если уж прям хочется исключить `/?controller` то напишите отдельное правило для пути `/` с RewriteCond на этот параметр